# Azure B2C - Link IdentityProvider to UserFlow causes 403 using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to configure an Azure B2C instance. Specifically, I need to create *UserFlows* and *IdentityProviders*. For this purpose, I have created an *AppRegistration* with *IdentityProvider.ReadWrite.All* and *IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All* API application permissions for the Microsoft Graph. I am able to call the APIs for creating new user flows and identity providers without a problem, but I am unable to link flows to an identity provider. Whenever I use any of the linking API's, I get an error:

**AADB2C (User Authorization: Access is denied)**

As an example, I get this when trying to list registered identity providers for specific user flow, i.e.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/B2C_1_{flowId}/identityProviders
```

The response for this request is a 403 with

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AADB2C",
    "message": "User Authorization: Access is denied.",
    "innerError": ...
  }
}
```

I am using the Beta API as described in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/b2cuserflows-list-identityproviders?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. I get the samme error when trying to link a user flow with an identity provider as described in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/b2cuserflows-update-identityprovider?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Any idea why I keep getting this authorization block?

Update: I have tried expanding the .IdentityProviders property on a userflow when reading it from the graph api. This does not give a 403, but the identity providers list, on the returned user flow, is empty even when providers have been manually added to the flow in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Please provide a request or correlation id and timestamp or date.

Comment: @AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity Here is a correlationId from a request failing with 403 trying to list identity providers for a user flow: 49557e54-296d-4115-9cf2-e555afee5474 (Date: 2020-09-21T18:59:52)

Comment: Make sure that you click "grant admin consent". See https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlwBo.png. If you still have this issue, you can decode your access token in https://jwt.io to see if it includes the `IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All` application permission. But even though I don't have the 403 error, I have another error `Resource not found for the segment 'identityProviders'.` Looks like this endpoint has not been available although the official document has already mentioned.

Comment: @AllenWu I have granted admin consent for the API permission, and I am able to use other APIs which require that permission. As for the segment error you are seeing. Are you sure you are accessing https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/**b2cUserFlows**/{id}/identityProviders and not https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/UserFlows/{id}/identityProviders?

Comment: Ah thank you for your reminder! I did confuse them. I'll test it and come back when I have new update. BTW, are you using client credential flow to get the access token?

Comment: Based on the test, same issue occurs with client credential flow from my side. But it works fine with auth code flow. Looks like this endpoint is not working well for application permission currently. Beta version is still in change.

Comment: @AllenWu Yeah, it looks like a bug in the Graph API implementation. I can't really use code flow for this, so I am hoping AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity can provider further insights

Comment: @AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity Were you able to find anything from the correlationId I have you, or can I give you any more diagnostics information to help you track down the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure to comply with this:

> The work or school account needs to belong to one of the following
> roles:
>
> Global administrator External Identity User Flow administrator